# How to upload files in mailbox plugin

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I am trying to upload file in mailbox plugin [wordpress] , it shows an error like `increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 5M`..

Comment: so why don't you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `php.ini` file on your server. You need to go into your server, into the PHP folder and find the `php.ini` file. In there, there are these two settings: `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`. You need to set those to 5M for 5 megs.

Here's a tutorial for WordPress: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-maximum-upload-size-and-find-phpini - however, this shows how to do it on a Windows system. On Linux, this will be different.

In case you really don't know what I'm talking about - you could consider asking your hosting provider for help.